# How can I replace some text with another in linux console using a pipe?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, console

I have some text content.

I want to replace text in `[]` with `!!!` using pipes.
I can use this script: `cat myfile | sed -r 's/\[.+\]/!!!/'`

How can I do it multiline, so `.` can handle CR, LF, etc?
Maybe awk, perl or something similar?
The simplest solution is preferable.

Comment: `some text with another using pipes`.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Could you please give an example input & expected output? That'll make things more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl is a good choice for this:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\[.*?\]/!!!/gs' myfile
```

An example

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\[.*?\]/!!!/gs' << END
this is [some
text in brackets] blah blah
END
```

```
this is !!! blah blah
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. What does -0777 do? What is `0777 record separator` ?

Comment: That's tells perl to slurp the entire file into the default `$_` variable. That is required because there may be any number of newlines, including consecutive newlines, between the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 'H; $ {x;s/\[.+\]/!!!/p;}' myfile
```

sed work by default line by line so there is no CR LF by default. The H, catch every line at read in a buffer, $ react on last line (so all file is buffered including CR), x retreive the buffer and your sed is apply on the whole before p print the result (-n of sed remove other output than specified print)